# How to parse json response using SwiftyJson. Below is my code and response

Tags: parsing, swift3, swifty-json

```
func authenticateUser()
{    

    Alamofire.request("http://dev.myvmanager.com/vManagerMobileWebService/api/vMobile/Authenticate_iNotifications?username=ssrikanth&password=bA2135&device=iPhone&device_token=iPhone&sitekey=C0d3b33s@)!@").responseJSON
        {
            response in
            debugPrint(response)     
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use this constructor from SwiftyJSON and input the response data

```
Alamofire
    .request("http://dev.myvmanager.com/vManagerMobileWebService/api/vMobile/Authenticate_iNotifications?username=ssrikanth&password=bA2135&device=iPhone&device_token=iPhone&sitekey=C0d3b33s@)!@")
    .responseJSON { response in
        debugPrint(response)
        if let actualData = response.data {
            let json = JSON(data: actualData)
            debugPrint(json)
     }
}
```

Retrieve data from json

```
let json = JSON(data: actualData)
if let userName = json[0]["login_name"].string {
    //Now you got your value
}
```

For more information please look at https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON and the example project.

Here is also a nice comparison of JSON mappers

https://github.com/bwhiteley/JSONShootout

Comment: When i implement the above line, i get an error like this
"cannot convert value of type data response to expected argument type data"

Comment: @SachitPhilip after testing it I got this error _Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<Any>' to expected argument type 'Data'_ -> I updated my answer and it should hopefully work now

Comment: @ KaraBenMemsi 

i got a response like this now
[
  {
    "Description" : null,
    "Message" : null,
    "vmanager_account" : "True",
    "user_id" : "174",
    "login_name" : "ssrikanth",
    "user_name" : "Surya Srikanth",
    "owner_id" : "1",
    "user_email" : "srikanth@codebees.com",
    "customer_id" : "20",
    "vmanager_cc" : "True",
    "vmanager_tp" : "True",
    "customer_name" : "vCom Solutions",
    "is_so" : "0"
  }
]

suppose if i want to retrieve a value from this..for example "login_name"
how to do that?

Comment: thankyou so much. Your a lifesaver. 
Also i have one more doubt. I have hardcoded all the fields in url now. Suppose if this is the url 

"http://dev.myvmanager.com/vManagerServiceDev/api/vMobile/Authenticate_iNotifications
"
and i want to pass the following parameters in a get request
"username": text from textfield,
"password": text from textfield,
"device": "iPhone",
"device_token" = "iPhone", 
"sitekey"= "testsite"

what should be done?

Comment: @SachitPhilip you could probably do something like this: `"http://domain.com/path?username=\(textfield.text)&password=\(othertextfield.text)"` and so on

Comment: Is there any way i can pass the parameters without harcoding it in the url. The url is " http://dev.myvmanager.com/vManagerMobileWebService/api/vMobile/Authenticate_iNotifications"
 and the parameters are the ones i mentioned above.

Basically im working on a login page and once login button is pressed, a get request should be called with that url and parameters.

Comment: @SachitPhilip the same way as I described in the previous comment: `http://domain.com/path?\(paramNameOne)=\(textfield.text)&\(paramNameTwo)=‌​\(othertextfield.tex‌​t)`

Comment: @SachitPhilip or iterate over a e.g. dictionary and append the param value pairs accordingly